# Gulp doesn't write result to file

Tags: javascript, less, gulp

I have a `gulpfile.js` that looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
less = require('gulp-less'),
minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src(['less/*.less'])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(concat('everything.css'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('asset/'));
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src(['javascript/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('everything.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('asset/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('javascript/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch('less/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

As I was developing, the less task stopped working out of the blue. The console doesn't throw any errors, everything looks just like it should but the everything.css file does not get updated. I even removed the file and it doesn't get created again.

I'm compeltely clueless to what's going on, even rebooted my computer as a sanity check but it didn't help.

EDIT:
So apparently it's the `less` pipe. But why did it start to fail suddenly?

Comment: remove all the extra `less` steps until you have something that works, then add them back in until you find the problem.

Comment: @Mathletics Well apparently it's the less task. Just keeping `src` and `dest` there will copy the less files from `less` to `asset` but even when there only is the `less` pipe in between it stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your less files a bit, to simplify. This is a common design pattern, and it works very well for me:

```
/*main.less*/
@import "somefile.less"
@import "some/deep/nested/file.less"
```

In your other less files, those will be where you keep your actuall `less` code.

Then in your `gulpfile.js` you will want to modify a bit:

```
...
gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src(['less/main.less']) //only pull in your main.less file
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('asset/'));
});
...

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('javascript/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch('less/*.less', ['less']); //this remains the same - you want to watch for all changes
});
```

**Note:** `gulp.watch` will not find new files - you will need to restart when you have new files, or use something like `gulp-watch`.

This will solve all kinds of headaches for you. Hope it helps!

Comment: This answer helped me solve the problem! Turns out I was missing a semicolon in a LESS file but for some reason the compiler was quiet about it. FML.